# Change [tr][tr]{X} into [tr][tr]{\tinyX} in a long list of files within bash?

Tags: bash, replace

Newbie here. I am trying to program a bash script that will replace, for each file in a folder, the following sequence:
 `[tr][tr]{X}` where X is any decimal number (collection of digits and ".") with 
`[tr][tr]{\tinyX}`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: yes, many ideas

Comment: Are those literal strings `open-square-bracket t r` or regular expressions matching either t or r?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to GNU `sed`, you can also use `perl` (whose `-i` GNU `sed` actually borrowed):

```
find . -type f -exec perl -Tpi -e 's/\Q[tr][tr]{\E\K[\d.]+\}/\\tiny$&/g' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed` using the global replacement pattern `s/regexp/replacement/g`:

```
sed -i'' 's/\(\[tr\]\[tr\]{\)\([0-9.]\+}\)/\1\\tiny\2/g' /path/to/folder/*
```

This captures the string `[tr][tr]{` in one group and `X` containing at least one digit or `.` (bracket expression `[0-9.]\+`, the `\+` matches the characters inside the brackets one or more times) followed by the closing `}` in a second group and replaces the matched parts with the first group, `\tiny` and the second group in each line. The parentheses `()` for the groups, the literal brackets `[]`, `+` and the literal backslash `\` need to be escaped with another backslash.

Make sure to backup your data folder before running this (or use `-i.back` instead of `-i''` to keep the originals as `filename.back`).

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm!